# Confusion Regarding Definition of Lie Derivative

Tags: definition, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, solution-verification, lie-derivative

I am having some trouble reconciling two definitions for the Lie derivative.

Let $X$ be a vector field on a smooth manifold, $M$, and let $\varphi_t(x)$ be the local flow through the point $x \in M$. Then, the usual formulation of the Lie derivative of a vector field, $Y$, at a point, $a \in M$, is

$$
\mathcal{L}_X Y (a) := \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{(D\varphi_{-t})(Y(\varphi_t(a))) \, - \, Y(a)}{t}
$$

However, in the lecture notes I am using, the Lie derivative is defined as

$$
\mathcal{L}_X Y (a) := \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}((\varphi_t)_*Y)(a)\right]_{t=0}
$$

When I unroll the definitions in the second formulation, I get a slightly different result to the usual definition of the Lie derivative (see below).

---

Where am I going wrong:

The second definition is given by

\begin{align}
& \quad \,\, \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}((\varphi_t)_* Y)(a)\right]_{t=0} \\
&= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{((\varphi_{t})_* Y)(a) \, - \, ((\varphi_{0})_*Y)(a) }{t} \\
&= \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{((\varphi_{t})_* Y)(a) \, - \, Y(a)}{t}
\end{align}

Hence, to reconcile this with the usual definition, we want to show $((\varphi_{t})_* Y)_a = (D\varphi_{-t})Y_{\varphi_t(a)}$ (where, for ease of notation, we have moved the point at which we are evaluating the vector field to the subscript).

But, for $f \in C^\infty{M}$

\begin{align}
& \,\, \quad ((\varphi_{t})_* Y)_a(f) \\
&= ((D\varphi_t) Y_{\varphi_{t}^{-1}(a)})(f) \\
&= ((D\varphi_t) Y_{\varphi_{-t}(a)})(f) \\
&= Y_{\varphi_{-t}(a)}(f \circ \varphi_t)
\end{align}

whereas

\begin{align}
& \,\, \quad ((D\varphi_{-t})Y_{\varphi_t(a)})(f) \\
&= Y_{\varphi_t(a)}(f \circ \varphi_{-t})
\end{align}

This seems to show that the two definitions for the Lie derivative agree only up to sign. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Normally, we define the Lie derivative as the derivative of the pullback vector field by the flow: $\dfrac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} (\phi_t)^*Y$, but in your second definition, there is a pushforward by time $t$, i.e $(\phi_t)_*Y$, rather than a pullback. There are related as $(\phi_t)_* = \left((\phi_t)^{-1}\right)^* = (\phi_{-t})^*$ (pushing forward is same as pulling back by the inverse). This is why when taking the derivative at $t=0$ using the second definition, you get an extra minus sign

Answer (score 2):

The first definition is the correct one, the second one measure the derivative through the flow $t \mapsto \varphi_{-t}$ which is just the orginal one with the sign changed.